# Display Even Indices in an Array

Tags: php, for-loop

I'm trying to display only the even Indices of an array, but it's not working.

Here is my code:

```
$color = array( "Red", "Pink", "Blue", "Baby Blue", "Green", "Lime", "Gray", "Sunshine");

for ($i = 0; $i < count($color); $i++) {
     if ($color[$i] % 2 === 0) {
        echo "$i is $color";
     }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Define "it's not working".

Comment: To calculate the modulus, you'll want to use the numeric value of `$i` rather than the string value of `$color[$i]`. I.e. `if ($i%2==0)`.

Comment: You talk about  _array indexes_ then do the actual calculations on the  _array values_. i.e. `$i` (array index) and `$color[$i]` (array value). imo, Do the 'even' calculation on the array index (`$i`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is on line #4 mainly and line #5 partially:

```
$color = array( "Red", "Pink", "Blue", "Baby Blue", "Green", "Lime", "Gray", "Sunshine");

for ($i = 0; $i < count($color); $i++) {
     if ($i % 2 === 0) { // <- here
        echo "$i is ".$color[$i];
     }
}
```

You code was essentially equating to:

```
if ('Red' % 2 === 0) { // with every single color
```

Since you are using an indexed array, another way of achieving what you need is:

```
foreach ($color as $k=>$v) {
     if ($k % 2 === 0) {
        echo "$k is $v";
     }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

An easier way to do this is to just add two instead of one in your for loop.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($color); $i+=2) {
    echo "$i is $color[$i]";
}
```

Comment: It's the simple things in life that make me upvote :-)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add the index of `$color` as `$i` like: `$color[$i]`. and miss check the condition.

```
$color = array( "Red", "Pink", "Blue", "Baby Blue", "Green", "Lime", "Gray", "Sunshine");

for ($i = 0; $i < count($color); $i++) {
     if ($i % 2 === 0) { //Here miss check
        echo "$i is $color[$i]"; //here missing index
     }
}
```

For simplicity: Remove the if condition.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($color); $i+=2){
    echo "$i is $color[$i]"; //here missing index
}
```

Comment: Its very bad thing to give downvote at valid answer.

Comment: I didn't downvote (the first part seems fine to me), but the second part you added has a couple of problems.

Comment: problem? What problem, can you mention?

Comment: Missing opening bracket, subtracting from `$i` inside the array index within the string gives a syntax error, and it prints more than just the even items.